# How do I embed a custom website font in ttf format for all browsers?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, truetype

On my website I'm using a custom font which I have uploaded. It seems to be choosing when to work intermittently. It works on some computers/browsers, but not on others. It is also mapped correctly.

This is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AgencyFBRegular';
    src: url('agencyr.eot');
    src: url('agencyr.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('agencyr.woff') format('woff'),
         url('AGENCYR.TTF') format('truetype'),
         url('agencyr.svg#AgencyFBRegular') format('svg');
}


h3 {    font-family: 'Agency FB', sans-serif; font-size: 26px; font-weight:normal; text-align: left; line-height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom:7px; 
</style>
```

I thought it was working everywhere until I used a friend's laptop to view it.

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE:
I have updated font CSS. It seems to be working, but now not on iOS.

Comment: Your only embedding a `TTF` font, you need the specific format for each browser your targetting. Checkout: http://caniuse.com/ttf, also check out http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

Comment: I viewed it in the same browser?

Answer (score 36):

The following code should work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"AgencyFBRegular";
    src: url("agencyr.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"AgencyFBRegular";
    src: url("agencyr.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}

h3 {
    font-family:'Agency FB', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need change file name of your font without Uppercase. Like this: from `AGENCYR.TTF` to `agencyr.ttf`

and in your css file:

```
src: url('agencyr.ttf');
```